# Searching through file on Perl

Tags: perl, search

Okay so I need to read in a file, go through each line and find where there is the string ERROR.  This is what I have so far:

```
open(LOGFILE, "input.txt") or die "Can't find file";

$title = <LOGFILE>;

$\=' ' ;
while (<>){
    foreach $title(split){
        while (/^ERROR/gm){
            print "ERROR in line $.\n";
        }
    }
}
close LOGFILE;
```

So the problem that I have is that it only looks at the first word of each line.  So if the input is

boo far ERROR

It won't register an error.  any help would be greatly appreciated!  I'm new to perl so please try and keeps things basic.  Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a job for `grep`: `grep -n ERROR input.txt`.

Comment: @TLP Definitely the best way to do it. Feel free to add an edit to my answer with that if you want.

Comment: @kevlar1818 It depends on what OS the OP is using. I felt it was more suitable as a comment than an answer.

Comment: @TLP Well then I will add it as an aside to my answer, if that's ok with you?

Comment: @kevlar1818 Go ahead. You should cite your source as a courtesy. Not that I care about the credit, but I think it is the polite thing to do.

Comment: Some issues with your code: 1) no `use strict; use warnings;`; 2) hardcoded input filename, make it an argument and <> will read the contents for you 3) the `$title(split)` part doesn't make any sense, you need to acquire a basic understanding of standard programming constructs and Perl syntax. 4) Don't recreate wheels that others have already dispensed to you freely, well-tested and well-documented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a more elegant approach, and I fixed the regex issue. `^` matched the start of a line.

```
open(LOGFILE, "input.txt") or die "Can't find file";

while(<LOGFILE>) {
   print "ERROR in line $.\n" if(/ERROR/);
}
close LOGFILE;
```

Or how about from the command line:

```
perl -n -e 'print "ERROR in line $.\n" if(/ERROR/);' input.txt
```

`-n` implicitly loops for all lines of input
`-e` executes a line of code

To output to a file:

```
perl -n -e 'print "ERROR in line $.\n" if(/ERROR/);' input.txt > output.txt
```

While this is a good/simple example of using Perl, if you're using a Unix shell, [grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) does what you want with no need for scripting (thanks to TLP in the OP comments):

```
grep -n ERROR input.txt > output.txt
```

This is actually prints the matching line itself, with its line number.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much!  Now I need to have it write out to a file which lines have errors.  I'm familiar with Python, so Perl is new to me.

Comment: If this worked, feel free to accept it, or +1 it at least :-).

Comment: I can't +1 it yet because my reputation is not at 15 yet. But thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Of course it won't, because ^ in front of your regexp means "start of line". Remove it and it will catch ERROR anywhere. You shouldn't do any splitting tricks either. You need to find ERROR anywhere? Then just write so:

```
while (<>){
   if (/ERROR/){
      print "ERROR in line $.\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: Okay! So I removed ^ but now the message prints as many times as there are words in the line even if there is only one ERROR. For ex,                 foor bar bar ERROR                            would give me ERROR in line 1 four times even though ERROR is only found once.